# Is there a way to update Qt components in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm developing apps for Meego. The Qt components comes with Qt Creator have some bugs, and they are obviously fixed in the latest version on Gitorious. So I would like to update my local libs and get those new features and fixes. The SDK maintenance tool could not do this. Is there a way to update the components?

Answer (score 2):

If you download and build them on your machine, then go into the settings you can specify which version of QMake you want to use, which then pulls in the relevant libs & includes for it, that'll let you jump to the latest versions.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm quite new to this (QML and Web background). I know how to download the source code from Gitorious, but what to do next? Thanks a lot! (I'm using Mac OS X Lion)

Comment: Sure thing, you pull the source down and fire up Terminal, cd into the folder and theres a configure script in there, type ./configure --help and work out which options you'll need. There should be a set of instructions for building it from there but it's generally `./configure <options> && make && make install`